# How do I use uncompyle6

Tags: installation, terminal, python, osx-yosemite, ableton-live

I am new to Python. I have version 2.7.11 installed on my MacBook Pro, running Yosemite 10.10.5. I am trying to figure this out because I would like to decompile the scripts to the Native Instruments Maschine, take a look at them and create some of my own for use with Ableton Live.

I can't seem to get any further than the fact the uncompyle2, uncompyle6 and spark-parser have all been downloaded into my .../Python/2.7/site-packages folder. Typing in the shell $ uncompyle -h doesn't do anything either.

I'm stuck and this is starting to increase the fury inside and I'm afraid I may go on a terrible rampage if I don't figure this out. I've looked all over the interwebs and can't find a single, detailed explanation on how to do this. I need an explanation similar to Reddit's 'like I'm 5' so I can actually see and learn what I am doing.

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried running the commands in the "Installation", "Testing", and "Usage" sections of https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6 ?

Comment: @DavidCary I'm not really sure how to properly execute these commands in the terminal
# Please explain like I'm 5.

Answer (score 1):

The command you run is called when you install uncompyle6 is `uncompyle6`, not `uncompyle`. The command you run when you install incompyle2 is `uncompyle2`.

Both of these programs require a compiled Python program. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822335/what-do-the-python-file-extensions-pyc-pyd-pyo-stand-for) for a discussion of what the .pyo and .pyc extensions mean.

There was a bug in earlier versions of uncompyle6 that didn't install the script files correctly. So if `uncompyle6` isn't found, try installing a newer package using `pip install uncompyle6` (if you are using a virtual python setup) or `sudo pip install uncompyle6` if you want to install system wide using the system python, as you probably want to do.